# Using interfaces in DbContext and DbSets for similar databases

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 3 sqlite databases, and each has only one table called "Logs".
These "Logs" tables have different columns:

> ```
> Database1.db
>   Logs(Id, VarA, VarB)
>
> Database2.db
>   Logs(Id, VarC, VarD)
>
> Database3.db
>   Logs(Id, VarE, VarF)
> ```

I've modeled this with EntityFramework 6 as follows:

```
public class Database1Log
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public float? VarA { get; set; }
     public float? VarB { get; set; }
}

public class Database2Log
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public float? VarC { get; set; }
     public float? VarD { get; set; }
}

public class Database3Log
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public float? VarE { get; set; }
     public float? VarF { get; set; }
}
```

I also have 3 different DbContext:

```
public class Database1DbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Database1Log> Logs { get; set; }

    public Database1DbContext ()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<Database1DbContext >(null);
    }
}

public class Database2DbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Database2Log> Logs { get; set; }

    public Database2DbContext ()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<Database2DbContext >(null);
    }
}

public class Database3DbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Database3Log> Logs { get; set; }

    public Database3DbContext ()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<Database3DbContext >(null);
    }
}
```

**Question:** 
Is it possible to refactor the following code using interfaces and/or inheritance?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args[0].Equals("Database1")) 
        {
            var dbContext = new Database1DbContext();
            var logs = dbContext.Logs();

            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(logs));
        }
        else if (args[0].Equals("Database2")) 
        {
            var dbContext = new Database2DbContext();
            var logs = dbContext.Logs();

            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(logs));
        }
        else if (args[0].Equals("Database3")) 
        {
            var dbContext = new Database3DbContext();
            var logs = dbContext.Logs();

            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(logs));
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```
public interface ILog
{ 
    int Id { get; set; }
}

public interface IDbContext
{ 
    DbSet<ILog> Logs { get; set; }
}

public class Database1DbContext : DbContext, IDbContext
{
    public DbSet<ILog> Logs { get; set; }

    public Database1DbContext ()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<Database1DbContext >(null);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Database1Log>()
            .HasKey(u => u.Id)
            .ToTable("Logs");
    }
}

public class Database2DbContext : DbContext, IDbContext
{
    public DbSet<ILog> Logs { get; set; }

    public Database2DbContext ()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<Database2DbContext >(null);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Database2Log>()
            .HasKey(u => u.Id)
            .ToTable("Logs");
    }
}

public class Database3DbContext : DbContext, IDbContext
{
    public DbSet<ILog> Logs { get; set; }

    public Database3DbContext ()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<Database2DbContext >(null);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Database3Log>()
            .HasKey(u => u.Id)
            .ToTable("Logs");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IDbContext dbContext = null;
        List<ILog> logs = null;

        if (args[0].Equals("Database1")) 
        {
            dbContext = new Database1DbContext();
        }
        else if (args[0].Equals("Database2")) 
        {
            dbContext = new Database2DbContext();
        }
        else if (args[0].Equals("Database3")) 
        {
            dbContext = new Database3DbContext();
        }

        logs = dbContext.Logs();

        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(logs));
    }
}
```

But it throws:

`The type 'ConsoleApp.Models.ILog' was not mapped. Check that the type has not been explicitly excluded by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Verify that the type was defined as a class, is not primitive or generic, and does not inherit from EntityObject.`

Comment: what line does it throw the exception?

Answer (score 0):

You could use some kind of factory or injection since youre predicating *which type* of database to instantiate based on a string input from the user/program. Maybe start down a path like this:

```
public interface IDbContext
{
    DbSet<ILog> Logs { get; set; }
}

public interface IDbContextFactory
{
    IDbContext CreateDb(string type);
}
```

Then the actual factory:

```
public class DbFactory : IDbContextFactory
{
    public IDbContext Create(string name)
    {
        if (name == "1")
        {
            return new Database1DbContext();
        }
        // else if 2
        // else if 3
    }
}
```

Then your consuming code could look something like:

```
IDbContextFactory factory = new DbContextFactory();
IDbContext db = factory.Create(args[0]);
DbSet<ILog> logs = db.Logs;
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(logs));
```

Comment: I'm getting `Error: The type 'ConsoleApp.Models.ILog' was not mapped. Check that the type has not been explicitly excluded by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Verify that the type was defined as a class, is not primitive or generic, and does not inherit from EntityObject.` when instantiating any of the DbContexts

Comment: unless you update your code with what you tried, it will be difficult to troubleshoot this error